# How to add a custom log with az cli?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-log-analytics

[In the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace/table?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-log-analytics-workspace-table-create), it shows how to create a table, but I see no parameter for setting the collection paths for custom logs (ex: /etc/log/nginx/error.log) the way you can in the portal.

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace table create --name
                                                --resource-group
                                                --workspace-name
                                                [--columns]
                                                [--description]
                                                [--no-wait]
                                                [--plan {Analytics, Basic}]
                                                [--retention-time]
                                                [--total-retention-time]
```

When I use show on a current table, I also don't see any collection path parameters or links to other objects where that might be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As far as I know and as per this [Git Hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34054) document, adding custom logs using Azure CLI is still a feature request.*

> [@LawrenceLLo](https://github.com/LawrenceLLo) AFAIK, Azure CLI currently doesn't support the above scenario. If this is something you would like to see supported, kindly share the feedback directly with the feature owner using [this link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/913690-azure-monitor).

*Looks like there is already a feature request is in place, I would suggest you to Upvote and make a comment. Engineering will monitor this product feedback actively.
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/579dea67-2125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f09d0*

Comment: @Patrick check out the updated answer